# Curly bracket confusion!

Tags: awk

Curly brackets question, with this file content.

```
one one one

two two two

three 098234

one one one

two two two

three 098234

one one one

two two two

three 098234 ...
```

---

```
awk '{ a[NR]=$0 } END {b=0; for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) { b++; printf "%s",a[i]; if(b==3) {print"";b=0;}}}' file
```

**output:**

```
one one onetwo two twothree 098234

four four fourfive five fivesix 092834
 ...
```

Concatenate 3 lines, then add a newline!

The need or placement of curly brackets, is not understood correctly, although this works.
Would there be other ways of using curly brackets here, with same result?
I looked at many similar examples, I was unable to have the result wanted.

Not sure my question makes sense, but is there a simple **rule of thumb** to curly bracket. Thanks

Comment: The awk manual is a good place to start reading.

Answer (score 2):

Your `awk` statement might be better understood with explicit line breaks

```
awk '
         { a[NR]=$0 }    # Applies to every line of input

    END  {               # Executed once, when there is no more data
             b=0;
             for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
                 b++;
                 printf "%s",a[i];
                 if (b==3) {
                     print"";
                     b=0;
                 }
             }
         }
' file
```

Based on your requirement to concatenate every three lines of data, this looks to be very inefficient code as it reads in the entire file before doing any processing at all.

Try this instead, which only buffers three lines at a time:

```
awk '{s=s $0} NR>1&&!((NR)%3) {print s;s=""}' data
```

Expanded it looks like this

```
awk '
                    { s=s $0 }           # Append this line to the buffer
    NR>1 && !(NR%3) { print s; s="" }    # Print the buffer every three lines
' data
```

The expression on the first line `(NR%3)` reaches zero every third line. The `!` negates that so it only triggers the `{...}` component every third line.